How do I delete a pointer after assigning another pointer to that memory in C?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    typedef struct node
    {
        int number;
        struct node *next;
    }node;

    // create the pointer to the main list
    node *list;

    // allocate memory for temporary pointer
    node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));

    // assign first element of list
    n -> number = 1;
    n -> next = NULL;

    // have list point to temporary node n
    list = n;
    n -> number = 2;

    printf("%i\n", (list -> number));
}

I´m new to using pointers, and I´m trying to do an exercise but I ran into a problem. This program prints out 2, since list and n point at the same memory, but after I point list to 1, I want to get rid of the pointer n, without destroying or affecting the pointer list.
list = n;
free(n);

This ends up affecting list as well, and I can´t just malloc n again without changing list. This is basically the issue I´m facing, I need to remove the pointer "n" while leaving list intact, so I can malloc another temporary element, point this element to list, and so on. (I´m just getting introduced to the concept of linked lists, thank you for any advice or help in advance)

The variable that holds the pointer will automatically be erased when it goes out of scope. There is no need to free variables.

You dont free a pointer, you free memory that a pointer points to.

What do you mean by "delete"?  There's no reason for n to even exist in this code, so you could just delete it at the source level.  Or just wait until it goes out of scope.  eg { node * list; { node *n; ... /* do stuff with n */; } /* now n is out of scope*/;   After the }, you can think of n as having been "deleted", since it is no longer a valid identifier.

Thank you for the replies, some things I´m doing might seem redundant or unnecessary, but it´s just how the exercise is to understand the concept. I really appreciate the help!

Both list and n point at the same struct node. If you free(n) or free(list) both n and list will be "dangling" pointers and may not be dereferenced. Therefore, call free(n) (or free(list)) after printf("%i\n", (list -> number));.

After you do list = n; you can simply reassign n with a different pointer.

Style guide: the dot . and arrow -> operators bind very tightly
because they are postfix operators.
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing n -> number is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use n->number.

@Yi Yangna It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Style guide: move the typedef to file scope (i.e. above main). You'd have to do this if you split up the code into multiple functions. This is common enough that function scoped typedef or struct definitions are rarely (if ever) used.

thank you for the style guide, much appreciated@JonathanLeffler

@VladfromMoscow I am a newbie, so my code is not in fact achieving anything, sorry if the question seemed stupid hahaha

@CraigEstey thank you! I actually left it there just cause the example was really short, I´ll make sure to move it to file scope when I write the proper code

There a lot of good comments, but I thought I would do a bit of refactoring of your code to enlighten you to defining pointers and referencing them.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node *next;
} node;

int main (void)
{
    // Create the pointer to the structures
    node *list, *n, *x;

    // Allocate memory for the initial node
    list = malloc(sizeof(node));
    list -> number = 1;
    list -> next = NULL;

    n = list;                       /* Initialize the node work pointer to the intial node  */

    // Build some node structures and create a short list

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        x = malloc(sizeof(node));   /* Allocate memory for the next node in the list        */
        n->next = x;                /* Store the new address in the next address pointer    */
        x->number = n->number + 1;  /* Doing a simple incrementation of the value           */
        x->next = NULL;             /* Setup of the next node address pointer               */
        n = x;                      /* Temporary node pointer is set to the latest node     */
    }

    n = list;
    while (1)                       /* Do a simple display of what data has been created    */
    {
        if (n->next == NULL)
            break;
        printf("Node address: %p  Number: %d  Next address: %p\n", n, n->number, n->next);
        n = n->next;
    }

}

Basically, the food for thought here is that the pointer declarations are just variables capable of holding a memory address (in this case "list, n, and x").
And interpreting that your intended purpose is to create a list of node structures containing an integer value, a simple "for" loop was use to construct such a list and then list it out.
Following is the sample output at the terminal.
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Nodelist/bin/Release$ ./Nodelist 
Node address: 0x555cf4d0b2a0  Number: 1  Next address: 0x555cf4d0b2c0
Node address: 0x555cf4d0b2c0  Number: 2  Next address: 0x555cf4d0b2e0
Node address: 0x555cf4d0b2e0  Number: 3  Next address: 0x555cf4d0b300
Node address: 0x555cf4d0b300  Number: 4  Next address: 0x555cf4d0b320
Node address: 0x555cf4d0b320  Number: 5  Next address: 0x555cf4d0b340
Node address: 0x555cf4d0b340  Number: 6  Next address: 0x555cf4d0b360
Node address: 0x555cf4d0b360  Number: 7  Next address: 0x555cf4d0b380
Node address: 0x555cf4d0b380  Number: 8  Next address: 0x555cf4d0b3a0
Node address: 0x555cf4d0b3a0  Number: 9  Next address: 0x555cf4d0b3c0

Again, this is not a "this is what you did wrong or did right" narrative, but an example of how pointer usage can be set up and give you food for thought.  The other thing to take away is to dig into available tutorials either in book form or online on the usage of pointers and memory allocation.

Thank you so much! This was very helpful

Example code that uses a pointer to pointer to node to avoid having to handle the first node differently than the rest of the nodes and|or avoid using a dummy node. It also includes code to free the list (free every node in a list).
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

/* for older compilers: struct is node_, typedef is node */
typedef struct node_
{
    struct node_ *next;
    int number;
}node;

int main()
{
node *list = NULL;                      /* empty list */
node **ppnode = &list;                  /* ptr to ptr to node */
node *pnode;                            /* ptr to node */
node *pnext;                            /* ptr to next node */
int i;
    /* create list */
    for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
        pnode = malloc(sizeof(node));   /* allocate a node */
        pnode->number = i;
        pnode->next = NULL;
        *ppnode = pnode;                /* append to list */
        ppnode = &(pnode->next);        /* advance ppnode */
    }
    /* display list */
    for(pnode = list; pnode != NULL; pnode = pnode->next)
        printf("node: %p next: %p number: %2d\n",
               pnode, pnode->next, pnode->number);
     /* free list */
    pnode = list;
    while(pnode != NULL){
        pnext = pnode->next;
        free(pnode);
        pnode = pnext;
    }
    list = NULL;
    return 0;
}


Thank you! Compared to another option this still looks daunting to me, but I will carefully analyze it and try to wrap my head around it

@YiYangna - it may help to note that *ppnode is what is being set to the next allocated node. For the first node, it is used to set list, for the rest of the nodes, it is used to set node-next.  ppnode is similar to a pointer to a dummy node that only has a next pointer:  ppnode is equivalent to (pointer to dummy_node)->next.
